# Nodejs multiple file upload

Tags: node.js

So, I have this:

```
    async function uploadImageToFtp(fileName, path) {
      const client = new ftp.Client()
      client.ftp.verbose = true
      try {
        await client.access({
          host: process.env.FTP_HOST,
          user: process.env.FTP_USER,
          password: '123',
          secure: false
        })
        await client.uploadFrom(path, "tables/" + fileName)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      
client.close()
}

fs.readdir('plates', function(err, files) {
  //handling error
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
  }
  //listing all files using forEach
  files.forEach(function(file) {
    uploadImageToFtp(file, 'plates/' + file);
    console.log(file);
  });
});
```

But I get "too many FTP connections...".
So, how to wait for 1 file to upload and then to continue with seconds etc...?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `for-loop` instead of `forEach`, and use `async/await` completely for your example:

```
fs.readdir('plates', async function (err, files) { // async function, carefully this line, `readdir` still is a callback function
  //handling error
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
  }
  //listing all files using forEach
  for (const file of files) {
    await uploadImageToFtp(file, 'plates/' + file); // wait until it done
    console.log(file);
  }
});
```